# as.POSIXct not working for all dates with same format

Tags: r, posixct, lubridate

With these data:

```
Dat <- structure(list(IndID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = "BHS_017_A", class = "factor"), DateTimeUTC = structure(1:7, .Label = c("2015.03.07 06:00:36", 
"2015.03.07 11:00:49", "2015.03.07 16:00:36", "2015.03.07 21:00:41", 
"2015.03.08 02:00:36", "2015.03.08 07:00:36", "2015.03.08 12:00:36"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("IndID", "DateTimeUTC"), row.names = c(NA, 
-7L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am using the following code to convert dates to POSIXct dates.

```
Dat$Time <- as.POSIXct(strptime(as.character(Dat$DateTimeUTC),"%Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

However, when looking at the output below, an NA is generated for one of the the time values with what looks like the exact same format.  What am I missing here?

This is occurring a number of places in my dataframe but I have only posted a small reproducible example here.

```
head(Dat)

      IndID         DateTimeUTC                Time
1 BHS_017_A 2015.03.07 06:00:36 2015-03-07 06:00:36
2 BHS_017_A 2015.03.07 11:00:49 2015-03-07 11:00:49
3 BHS_017_A 2015.03.07 16:00:36 2015-03-07 16:00:36
4 BHS_017_A 2015.03.07 21:00:41 2015-03-07 21:00:41
5 BHS_017_A 2015.03.08 02:00:36                <NA>
6 BHS_017_A 2015.03.08 07:00:36 2015-03-08 07:00:36
```

Comment: Daylight savings time.

Comment: can you elaborate?  The conversion does not work because it is on daylight savings...?  If I have a full year of monitoring, I can expect an NA value for spring and fall time changes, is that correct?

Comment: Do know what 'spring forward' refers to?  That hour does not exist.  You have one day with 23 hours in the spring followed by one with 25 hours in the fall -- but only in localtime.  UTC does not adjust.

Comment: Well, the example you show is a datetime that literally never happened. At 2am on 2015-03-08 we jumped instantly to 3am. None of the intervening times actually took place. So yes, you'll get NA's for the spring times; for fall the behavior is I think a little more ambiguous, since you're repeating times, not skipping them.

Comment: If you don't like daylight savings time you can join the Standard Time movement :) http://www.standardtime.com/

Comment: Another possibly relevant Q&A: [Handling data on the days when we switch to daylight savings time and back in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865172/handling-data-on-the-days-when-we-switch-to-daylight-savings-time-and-back-in-r)

Comment: Thanks to all for the helpful comments and link to duplicate question.